# Rearrange dataframe by subsetting and column bind

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyr, cbind

I have the following dataframe:

```
st <- data.frame(
      se = rep(1:2, 5),
      X = rnorm(10, 0, 1),
      Y = rnorm(10, 0, 2))
st$xy <- paste(st$X,",",st$Y)
st <- st[c("se","xy")]
```

but I want it to be the following:

```
1   2   3   4   5
-1.53697673029089 , 2.10652020463275    -1.02183940974772 , 0.623009466458354   1.33614674072657 , 1.5694345481646  0.270466789820086 , -0.75670874554064   -0.280167896821629 , -1.33313822867893
0.26012874418111 , 2.87972571647846 -1.32317949800031 , -2.92675188421021   0.584199000313255 , 0.565499464846637   -0.555881716346136 , -1.14460518414649  -1.0871665543915 , -3.18687136890236
```

I mean when the value of `se` is the same, make a column bind.

Do you have any ideas how to accomplish this?
I had no luck with `spread(tidyr)`, and I guess it's something which involves `sapply`, `cbind` and a `if` statement. Because the real data involves more than 35.000 rows.

Comment: Try, `library(dplyr); st %>% group_by(se) %>% mutate(idx = row_number()) %>% spread(idx, xy)`

Comment: thanks @docendodiscimus , it works perfect!

Comment: I do not understand the idx parameter in mutate, what it is?

Comment: It creates an index column within each group of se, that counts from 1, 2, 3,... . That index is then used as a key to spread the xy column. Just remove the last pipe element to see exactly what it does

Answer (score 0):

If we need to split the 'xy' column elements into individual units, `cSplit` from `splitstackshape` can be used.  Then `rbind` the alternating rows of 'st1' after `unlist`ing`.

```
library(splitstackshape)
st1 <- cSplit(st, 'xy', ', ', 'wide')
 rbind(unlist(st1[c(TRUE,FALSE)][,-1, with=FALSE]), 
    unlist(st1[c(FALSE, TRUE)][,-1, with=FALSE]))
```

---

If we don't need to `split` the 'xy' column into individual elements, we can use `dcast` from `data.table`.  It should be fast enough.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(st)`, create a sequence column ('N') by 'se', and then `dcast` from 'long' to 'wide'.

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(st)[, N:= 1:.N, se], se~N, value.var= 'xy')
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems as though your eventual goal is to have a data file which has roughly 35000 columns.  Are you sure about that?  That doesn't sound very [tidy](http://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.html).

To do what you want, you are going to need to have a row identifier.  In the below, I've called it caseid, and then removed it once it was no longer required.  I then transpose the result to get what you asked for.

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

st <- data.frame(
  se = rep(1:2, 5),
  X = rnorm(10, 0, 1),
  Y = rnorm(10, 0, 2))
st$xy <- paste(st$X,",",st$Y)
st <- st[c("se","xy")]
st$caseid = rep(1:(nrow(st)/2), each = 2) # temporary

df = spread(st, se, xy) %>%select(-caseid) %>%t()
print(df)
```