# R: Reshape data into a single row

Tags: r, reshape, reshape2

I have a data frame that looks something like this

```
A B    C
x 2013 23
x 2014 47
x 2015 83
```

I'd like to transform it so that I have all data and other dimensions for x in one row:

```
A B    C  D    E   F    G
x 2013 23 2014 47  2015 83
```

How can I do this using R? Can I use the Reshape package?

Many thanks,

Jim

Comment: Add a time variable based on "A" and reshape wide...

Comment: Or another  [recent Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35207472/rearrange-dataframe-by-subsetting-and-column-bind)

Comment: @Jaap I asked how this would be done using the Reshape package. Neither of the duplicate questions show that.

Comment: @Jim yes it does, based on the answer in the duplicate link: `dcast(setDT(mydf), A ~ rowid(A), value.var=c('B', 'C'))` after that you can rearrange and rename the columns